# 403 error when importing a new JSS app to Sitecore 10.2

Tags: sitecore, http-status-code-403

When trying to import a newly generated JSS application into Sitecore, the jss deploy app --includeContent --includeDictionary returns the following error:
**Unexpected response from import service:
Status message: Forbidden
Status: 403**

Version info:
Sitecore version 10.02
JSS Version: 19.0

For jss setup, I specify the Sitecore instance as **NOT** accessible via a network share.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be issue due to JSS version, i also had jss deploy issue, details are: https://rinkusitecore.wordpress.com/2021/03/20/app-deploy-issueforeach-import-for-sitecore-jss-using-sitecore-9-3/

It seems for sitecore 10.0, need jss version 15, checkout: https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_JavaScript_Services.aspx

So try to create your app based on jss version 10 like jss create  react -b release/15.0.0

But In your title you mentioned sitecore 10.2, in that case JSS version is correct ([https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/~/link.aspx?_id=B5D60A30ADD1495C9B011E793AF6884F&_z=z](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/%7E/link.aspx?_id=B5D60A30ADD1495C9B011E793AF6884F&_z=z))
So confirm it first.

Comment: I was able to resolve the 403 error by creating the app with the following command: PS C:\Sitecore> jss create sbxd-prj-one react --branch release/19.0.0

Comment: Its great that issue is resolved now, please upvote the answer as well.

Comment: I've tried upvoting the answer, but the site tells me that I need a 15 reputation before I may do so.  I'm new to this site, and to Sitecore, so  I'm sure I'll have may more questions which will get me to the level which will allow me to come back and upvote your answer.  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: np, i  too is new into it..once you collect points you can do that later.... :)