# Sitecore JSS (Headless) + React. Can not deploy app. Status: 403

Tags: reactjs, deployment, sitecore, headless, jss

I am trying to deploy my first react app.
I have followed all the steps according to the instructions.
But when it comes to app deployment I keep getting the same message.

Unexpected response from import status service. The import task is probably still running; check the Sitecore logs for details.
Status message:
Status: [403]

Can anyone help me with this?

[Hosts added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBTTP.png)

[Confings and the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EClCO.png)

[Api is working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPp4K.png)

Answer (score 0):

please go through my comment on : [403 error when importing a new JSS app to Sitecore 10.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71596112/403-error-when-importing-a-new-jss-app-to-sitecore-10-2)

- also make sure your API key and layout service is configured properly e.g. [http://myapp.siteco.re/sitecore/api/layout/render/jss?item=/&sc_apikey={YOUR_API_KEY_ID}](http://myapp.siteco.re/sitecore/api/layout/render/jss?item=/&sc_apikey=%7BYOUR_API_KEY_ID%7D)

Similar kind of issue: [403 error when importing a new JSS app to Sitecore 10.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71596112/403-error-when-importing-a-new-jss-app-to-sitecore-10-2/71657342#71657342)